# How to get the limit of the textarea using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, frameworks, selenium-webdriver

```
textareaCharecterLimit = _driver.findElement(By.xpath(value)).getAttribute("maximumlength")
return textareaCharecterLimit;
```

Comment: If you have that `maximumlength` tag, it should give you the limit.
For Ex:- i have tested the search box on the top right in Stackoverflow website. it has an attribute named as `maxlength` it returned the exact limit of 240 characters.

Comment: If HemChe's answer didn't make sense (it was a good one), please post the HTML that you are trying to get the max length of.

Comment: Its not necessary that developer has provided maximum length attribute in the html. so you need to check for it.